# Ionic event to identify user came from navCtrl.pop()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have three pages named as page1,page2 and page3

and their navigation will be page1->page2->page3

How we can identify on page2 that user came on this page via NavController Push or Pop function.

I just want to trigger a function on page2 only if they perform some action on page3 and redirected to page2 via navCtrl.pop() function.

I know i can put condition in ionViewWillEnter for last view name from nav stack, Because it will be fired everytime user be on page2. But If there is any other alternate or good way to do this. Please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifying if we came to a page using `push` is easy as it is the standard way of passing a parameter from `parent` to `child` in `navCtrl.push(PageName, parameters)`

I think what you are asking is how to do the opposite: pass a value back from `child` to `parent`.

Below is a solution for this (see [this link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5724) for details):

In parent, instead of the normal `push` function, create a new promise, and in the `then` part, you can get a parameter back from the child.

In child, after `pop()` call its `then`, and pass a parameter through the resolve of the promise that you initially created to the parent.

**Parent**

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.nav.push(ChildPage, {resolve: resolve});
}).then(data => {
  // process data
});
```

**Child**

```
this.nav.pop().then(() => this.params.get('resolve')('some data'))
```

I have used the above solution many times. There is also this alternative solution, but I haven't tested it myself:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic-navcontroller-pop-with-params/58104/3

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `globalThis['datatoinput']` to input my data and then using `ionViewDidEnter` on my parent page to read `globalThis['datatoinput']`